# Abstract class requires a property. I cannot use `private` when implementing the property. Why?

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract property in the Information class and I can't make it private in the Hypothesis class that extends it.

[image]

I'm using TSC 3.5.2 on Node 10.16.0 on Windows 8.1. The error shows in VS Code 1.36.1. The most relevant pages I've found are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4669) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32292).

```
abstract class Information {
  abstract collection: string;

  static retrieve(doc: string?): Promise<string | void | string[]> {
    let colRef = db.collection(this.collection)
      .doc(doc)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {})
  }
}
export default Information
```

and

```
import Information from "./information";

class Hypothesis extends Information { // Error 
  private collection: string = "hypotheses";
  //
}

export default Hypothesis;
```

I expected to be able to force inheriting classes to implement a private property. Instead, I got an error `Class 'Hypothesis' incorrectly extends base class 'Information'. Property 'collection' is private in type 'Hypothesis' but not in type 'Information'.`

I also expected to be able to say `abstract private collection...` or `private abstract collection` to fix this, but TS also says they're no bueno.

So I tried changing the code to this:

```
abstract class Information {
  abstract collection: string;
  ...
}
```

and

```
class Hypothesis extends Information { // Error 
  readonly collection: string = "hypotheses"; // or public, or nothing
  ...
}
```

It works.

Can someone explain why it works with `public`/`readonly` (or undeclared) and not with `private`/`protected`?

Comment: `private abstract` doesn't make sense. How are you going to implement an abstract field if it can not be seen, since it's private? You can do `protected abstract` instead.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was thinking private in implementation, not in the abstract class itself.

Comment: Well then you'd be better off using an interface instead of the class with readonly, I believe.